# How to set a mock sensor (accelerometer) in android device using programmatically

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

How to set a mock sensor on an Android device?

Is it possible to set a mock sensor using Android API or do we need to use NDK and JNI or use third party library?

Can anybody tell me how to implement this?

Comment: which sensor do you intent to mock ?

Comment: @TomerMor accelerometer and Gyroscope

Comment: two goods options: Genymotions, download apps that allowing you mocking sensors search in play store something like mock accelerometer or mock Gyroscope

Comment: @TomerMor I want to set programmatically

Comment: @mohan: Did you find a way to programmatically mock the sensors?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to simulate a gyroscope sensor and couldn't find a way, so I decided to do it myself. I'll leave it here if it helps anyone. The only requirement is: **you must have an accelerometer sensor in your device**. If you do, you can mock either the accelerometer or a gyroscope using a approach like this one:

1. Create a `SensorData`. This will be equivalent to `android.hardware.SensorEvent`. You will read sensor events from this class.

```java
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;

public class SensorData {
    public final long timestamp;
    public final int sensorType;
    public final float x;
    public final float y;
    public final float z;
    
    public static SensorData from(SensorEvent event) {
        final float[] values = event.values;
        return new SensorData(
            event.timestamp,
            event.sensor.getType(),
            values[0],
            values[1],
            values[2]
        );
    }
    
    public SensorData(long timestamp, int sensorType, float x, float y, float z) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.sensorType = sensorType;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

2. Create a `SensorDataListener`. This will be equivalent to `android.hardware.SensorEventListener`.

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;

public interface SensorDataListener {
    void onSensorChanged(SensorData data);

    void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy);
}
```

3. Create a `SensorProvider`. This will be equivalent to `android.hardware.SensorManager`. You'll have to subclass this class to implement your mock.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public abstract class SensorProvider implements SensorEventListener {
    protected final Context context;
    protected final SensorManager manager;
    protected SensorDataListener listener;
    
    public SensorProvider(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.manager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }
    
    public void register(SensorDataListener listener, int sensorType, int delay) {
        this.listener = listener;
        manager.registerListener(this, manager.getDefaultSensor(sensorType), delay);
    }
    
    public void unregister() {
        manager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}
    
    public abstract bool contains(int sensorType);
}
```

4.1. Create your mock. In this example, the accelerometer values will be the square root of the original accelerometer values and the gyroscope values will be the square of the original accelerometer values.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;

public class MockSensorProvider extends SensorProvider {
    public MockSensorProvider(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    
    @Override
    public bool contains(int sensorType) {
        return sensorType == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER ||
            sensorType == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        final SensorDataListener listener = this.listener;
        if (listener == null) return;
        
        final float[] values = event.values;
        final SensorData accData = SensorData(
            event.timestamp,
            Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,
            Math.sqrt(values[0]),
            Math.sqrt(values[1]),
            Math.sqrt(values[2])
        );
        listener.onSensorChanged(accData);
        
        final SensorData gyrData = SensorData(
            event.timestamp + 10,
            Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE,
            values[0] * values[0],
            values[1] * values[1],
            values[2] * values[2]
        );
        listener.onSensorChanged(gyrData);
    }
}
```

4.2. (optional) Create a static method in `SensorProvider` to get the current provider.

```
public abstract class SensorProvider implements SensorEventListener {
    // ...

    public static SensorProvider get(Context context) {
        return new MockSensorProvider(context);
    }

    // ...
}
```

5. It's done. You can use the `SensorProvider` like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorDataListener {
    private SensorProvider provider;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        provider = SensorProvider.get(this);
        if (provider.contains(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)) {
            provider.register(this, Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, 20000);
        }
        if (provider.contains(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)) {
            provider.register(this, Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE, 20000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        provider.unregister();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorData data) {
        Log.d("%d %.2f %.2f %.2f".format(data.timestamp, data.x, data.y, data.z));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer gave me a good basement to start from, but I think I've found an easier way to achieve the same result without substituting java classes and by only modifying the actual `SensorEvent` (thanks java for mutable properties by default).

Create a `CustomSensorEventListener` interface with stored `originalListener` and inherit from `SensorEventListener`

```
interface CustomSensorEventListener : SensorEventListener {
    var originalListener: SensorEventListener?
}
```

Modify sensor values as you wish in `onSensorChanged` callback.

```
override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onSensorChanged: original value: ${event?.values?.joinToString()}")
    event?.values?.forEachIndexed { index, value -> event.values[index] = value * value }

    originalListener?.onSensorChanged(event)
}
```

Then create `SystemSensorsManager` interface and implementation like this:

```
interface SystemSensorsManager {

    fun getDefaultSensor(type: Int): Sensor?

    fun registerListener(
        systemSensorListener: SensorEventListener,
        sensor: Sensor?,
        sensorDelay: Int
    ): Boolean

   fun unregisterListener(systemSensorListener: SensorEventListener, sensor: Sensor?)
}

class SystemSensorsManagerImpl(context: Context) : SystemSensorsManager {
    private val sensorManager = context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as? SensorManager

    private val customSystemSensorEventListener: CustomSensorEventListener =
    CustomSensorEventListenerImpl()

    override fun getDefaultSensor(type: Int): Sensor? {
       return sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(type)
    }

    override fun registerListener(systemSensorListener: SensorEventListener, sensor: Sensor?, sensorDelay: Int): Boolean {
        customSystemSensorEventListener.originalListener = systemSensorListener
        return sensorManager?.registerListener(
            customSystemSensorEventListener,
            sensor,
            sensorDelay
        ) ?: false
    }

    override fun unregisterListener(systemSensorListener: SensorEventListener, sensor: Sensor?) {
        sensorManager?.unregisterListener(
            customSystemSensorEventListener, sensor)
    }
}
```

And finally, register listeners on sensors you're interested in and provide the actual listener. For example, in `MainActivity` as it is in the previous answer:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener {
    private val systemSensorsManager: SystemSensorsManager by lazy {
        SystemSensorsManagerImpl(applicationContext)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val sensor = systemSensorsManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        systemSensorsManager.registerListener(
            systemSensorListener = this,
            sensor = sensor,
            sensorDelay = sensor!!.minDelay
        )
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        systemSensorsManager.unregisterListener(
            systemSensorListener = this,
            sensor =
systemSensorsManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    )
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onSensorChanged: modified value: 
${event?.values?.joinToString()}")
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {

    }
}
```